# call soap wsdl using jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, web-services, jquery-ui

I have a webservice written in java and exposed using axis2server.I need to call the service using jquery.My UI is hosted in same machine but in different port(8080). I tried the following code

```
$('#submit').click(function (event) {
    alert("success");
    var soapmessage = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' " + " xmlns:iris='http://iris.ramco.com'>";
    soapmessage += "<soap:Header/>";
    soapmessage += "<soap:Body>";
    soapmessage += "<iris:authenticateUser>";
    soapmessage += "<inputjson>                {username:'admin',password:'admin12*'}</inputjson>";
    soapmessage += "</iris:authenticateUser>";
    soapmessage += "</soap:Body>";
    soapmessage += "</soap:Envelope>";
    alert(soapmessage);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        url: 'http://localhost:8090/axis2/services/CiRISService',
        data: soapmessage,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("eror" + data.d);
        }
    });
    alert("Form Submitted");
});
```

But i get undefined error.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you get the `undefined error` ? are you sure you are including the jQuery library ? and note - you cannot do cross domain requests using AJAX

Comment: s am sure.. i get this undefined error..both my service and ui is hosted in the same local machine

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a SOAP client library? For example, there's a jQuery plugin: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient

And remember, you're never supposed to call SOAP methods directly, without specialized libraries. There are too many pitfalls you wouldn't expect.

Answer (score 0):

You are using content type `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` (and data type `"json"`) for a soap request. Instead try these

> contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
>
> dataType: "xml"

Edit: I agree with Shedal though, use a library.